# Gulp and Foundation: not compiling or what?

Tags: theming

Whenever I make changes in my zurb foundation file, those changes are not showing up on Zurb's them that I installed on my Drupal site.  Is this an issue of needing to compile with gulp?

The gulpfile.js content is the following.

```
 var gulp        = require('gulp'),
   livereload  = require('gulp-livereload'),
   uglify      = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
   browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
   sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
   autoprefixer= require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
   sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
   concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
   babel       = require('gulp-babel'),
   cp          = require('child_process'),
   imagemin    = require('gulp-imagemin'),
   pngquant    = require('imagemin-pngquant');
gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src('./themes/zurb_foundation/scss/foundation.sass')
 .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
 .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/zurb_foundation/css/foundation.css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./themes/zurb_foundation/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./themes/zurb_foundation/js/**/*.js', ['uglify']);
  gulp.watch(['./themes/zurb_foundation/css/foundation.css', 
  './themes/zurb_foundation/templates/*.twig', 
  './themes/zurb_foundation/js/**/*.js'], function (files){
    livereload.changed(files)
  });
});
```

Gulp watch is running fine, but no changes are being made when I reload and/or clear cache.  For example, in the zurb_foundation/scss/foundation/_global.scss file if I put the following CSS styles, nothing happens after `gulp watch`, clearing cache, and reloading are all down without any warnings being triggered.

```
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: A quick way to check this is to delete the compiled `*.css` file; when `gulp watch` is working properly, the file should be re-created as soon as you change `_global.scss`.  If it is not-- and that sounds like the case here-- it's an issue with gulp and has nothing to do with Drupal.

Comment: I went through and rewrote my gulpfile.js - it's definitely recreating the *.css file.  Ah, I think I need to get it to add the min.css suffix...I'm posting another question.  Thanks!